# difference bewteen *args and **args in python?

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, decorator

I am trying to understand the difference between *args and **args in function definition in python. In the below example, *args works to pack into a tuple and calculate the sum.

```
>>> def add(*l):
... sum = 0
... for i in l:
... sum+=i
... return sum ...
>>> add(1,2,3)
6
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>>add(*l)
6
```

for ** args,

```
>>> def f(**args):
...     print(args)
... 
>>> f()
{}
>>> f(de="Germnan",en="English",fr="French")
{'fr': 'French', 'de': 'Germnan', 'en': 'English'}
>>>
```

I see that it takes parameters and turns into a dictionary. But I do not understand the utility or other things that could be helpful when using ** args. In fact, I dont know what *args and **args are called(vararg and ?)

Thanks

Comment: For "I dont know what *args and **args are called": That's because there aren't really official names. The terms "var-positional parameter" and "var-keyword parameter" are used in a few places in the docs and in the source; PEP3102 uses "vararg parameter slot" and "keyword dictionary parameter slot". But those don't really trip off the tongue. People usually say something like "varags parameter" and "kwargs parameter".

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). For this question in particular, it has a whole section on [(somewhat) advanced function definitions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions). But really, the whole tutorial is quite good.

Comment: Also, "I see that it takes parameters and turns into a dictionary" is wrong. It takes (keyword) _arguments_ and turns them into a dictionary, which is passed to the single kwargs parameter. You can often get away with being loose about arguments and parameters, but in this area you're going to confuse yourself. [This blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/arguments-and-parameters.html) tries to explain it (and links to better explanations).

Comment: Finally, do you understand the point of keyword arguments in the first place? Because that's 90% of the answer to this question. `*args` gets all the excess positional arguments; `**kwargs` gets all the excess keyword arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use two asterisks you usually call them `**kwargs` for keyword arguments. They are extremely helpful for passing parameters from function to function in a large program.

A nice thing about keyword arguments is that it is really easy to modify your code. Let's say that in the below example you also decided that parameter `cube` is also relevant. The only thing you would need to do is add one `if statement` in `my_func_2`, and you would not need to add a parameter to every function that is calling `my_func_2`, (as long as that functions has `**kwargs`).

Here is a simple rather silly example, but I hope it helps:

```
def my_func_1(x, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('plus_3'):
        return my_func_2(x, **kwargs) + 3
    return my_func_2(x, **kwargs)

def my_func_2(x, **kwargs):
    #Imagine that the function did more work
    if kwargs.get('square'):
        return x ** 2
    # If you decided to add cube as a parameter 
    # you only need to change the code here:
    if kwargs.get('cube'):
        return x ** 3
    return x
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_func_1(5)
5
>>> my_func_1(5, square=True)
25
>>> my_func_1(5, plus_3=True, square=True)
28
>>> my_func_1(5, cube=True)
125
```

Comment: could be demonstrate with a simple example please?

Comment: Thats great simple example for understanding. Thanks